Dynamic variable with long text
Is there a way to set long text, with space, at Dynamic variables label in Anylogic? I suppose a java code its possible.
e.g., I would set the label name to "My long text", but only underscored "My_long_text" is allow due to java code requirements. A java code or a guide to set a long text at DV label.

again, what do you mean by "Dynamic variables label"? The blue text next to variables at runtime? share what you have & what you actually want, ideally with screenshots

You are not allowed to have variable names with spaces in Java or AnyLogic. This is final. If you really want to use spaces because they are very important to you for emotional or personal reasons, you need to use Another Software based on a different programming language.
I think you come from the Vensim world, which allows you to do that.
But, normally we AnyLogic users use the word "label" for something else... For example a button can have a label and that definitely allows spaces... so you are not talking about that

also, you can always use"Text" elements next to variables and these can display spaces or any other stuff you like
